# Iterate backwards with offset in FQL request for comments

Tags: sql, facebook, facebook-fql

I know how to get the most recent comments for a Facebook object via FQL:

```
SELECT id, fromid, text, time, likes, user_likes FROM comment
WHERE object_id = [FB_OBJ_ID] ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 25
```

How do I make subsequent requests to get the previous (older) batch of entries when the user clicks a button, so that every time the user asks for it I fetch the next batch of older posts. Ideally I can use the same query on every call with only an offset changing.

I'm familiar with offset and limit for the Graph API but can figure out how to use it in FQL to iterate *backwards* in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `OFFSET [(LIMIT_NO * n)+1]` to the end of your query, where `LIMIT_NO` is the number you are using in your `LIMIT` and `n` is the number of pages back you wish to go.

So to get the next 25 results, your query becomes

```
SELECT id, fromid, text, time, likes, user_likes FROM comment
WHERE object_id = [FB_OBJ_ID] ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 26
```